is there any way to add amps to a vintage battery charger using an additional transformer?
I have a 1970s vintage 10 amp transformer based battery charger and yes it has the old selenium rectifier.  I'd like to kick the amps up and I have a few transformers sitting around that were pulled from microwaves.
I was thinking there would be some way to cascade these so that they have higher amperage.
Example: if I have 3 different transformers and I get 4 volts from the first, 8 volts from the second (4 in 8 out) and 14 from the 3rd (8 in 14 out).  I'm just making up the numbers, but the numbers could be very low voltage at each step in order to get max amps.
I understand that you want to go parallel for max amps, but these transformers are all different, so I understand that has all kinds of problems if they don't match, so I wanted to avoid having to deal with that and see if there's another way.
My limited understanding is that when you setup the secondary, the higher you go in voltage, the lower you go in amps... so if I keep the voltage low for each transformer, would the amps be higher when you put them in series?

Even if you could just "add amps" by connecting more transformers to the input, the rest of the circuit won't be designed for additional current. You're creating a fire hazard.

@periblepsis I should have stated that I would be rewinding them.  I would keep the voltage very low in order to have higher amps and those amps and volts would be the primary on the next transformer.

It makes little sense to rewind random transformers to upgrade a vintage 12V 10A car battery charger made with just mains transformer and selenium rectifier. The rectifier would not handle more anyway. Build a new one from scratch. And as an example, likely a 1200W switch mode computer power supply is smaller than a 120W linear supply, so it also makes little sense to build a linear supply if you want more current.

You have transformers salvaged from microwave owens? If yes and you are going to use them, your life can get short. If you connect one to the mains AC only to see does it still be ok you generate kilovolts of AC which can kill you in a second if you happen to touch the high voltage output. The only possibility to use them safely is to start by disassembling the high voltage secondary before making any connection to mains AC. With a new properly calculated and made secondary winding it can be used in a higher power battery charger. But the rest of the parts must also be up to the task - full redesign! Only an experienced electrician who knows how to work with mains AC and also can do the engineering calculations can do the job properly. Others danger their home and life.
My suggestion: Do not try to connect the salvaged transformers. Buy a commercial battery charger which has the needed power.

One way to look at the transformers is that a core size (in a specific frequency) can deliver a fixed maximum power. This is because the core can store a limited amount of energy in each cycle.
If you have a transformer that can deliver 14V at 10A and is designed efficiently for the core to be close to saturation, then the core can be used to deliver 140W. This is where the reducing voltage/increasing current you mentioned comes from. As a ballpark figure, if you rewind and go to 7V, you can go up to 20A.
What you really want is, for a specific voltage, to get more current. This is more power. This means you will need a bigger core. The only way that you could use the same core is where the design was not efficient and the manufacturer chose a bigger core than is required. Because it's expensive to do so, it is very unlikely to happen in commercial products.
To summarize, for higher power, you will need a bigger core. This can be done by using a bigger physical core, or, as you mentioned, multiple transformers in parallel.
If the specs of the transformers are not identical, the current distribution will not be uniform. But it does not mean you can not do it. If the rating voltage of the output is exactly the same, after the rectifier, you can parallel them. If the current drawn by the smaller transformer will drop sooner because of the higher winding resistance that means more current will be drawn from the bigger transformer. However, after connecting a big load, monitor the current of each transformer to make sure it does not exceed its rating current.
Making transformers series will not help with higher power delivery. It will be limited by the transformer with the lowest power in the chain. The series transformers are only helpful in situations where you want to match the output voltage to what you want.

The 50Hz transformer and selenium rectifier scheme is common on vintage battery chargers .You will get more current into the battery when you replace the selenium with silicon diodes .Schottkey diodes are even better .On one hand the diodes waste much less power in the cabinet but the transformer copper will run hotter with the extra current .Check your temps into a big car battery that is reasonably flat .When I did this I turned 8 Amp into 10 Amp and was thermally still good .If you run too hot then put a computer fan on ,others have done this and it is satisfactory.

For battery charging the crucial parameter is voltage. So the transformers were designed primarily to step down the mains (230, 110 VAC) to appropriate value. So the primary and secondary loop counts are set.
The current is set by all resistances in the circuit, internal resistance of the battery, wires, resistors, rectifiers...
Based on that - voltage and resistances - estimated currents are calculated.
According to the estimated currents, the wire gauge for the coils is looked up (with engineering safety constant employed: It says 1.687246 mm diameter, I choose 5 mm)
Increasing current "capacity" of the charger does not help the charging much - at the same voltage the battery will drain the same current as before.
The confusion goes with USB charging where the charger and battery unit negotiate the parameters of the charging. But those chargers are pulse-width modulated chargers that can control effective current (root mean square value) by adjusting on/off ratio in the period. Peak current is dictated by the circuit resistance and voltage is set.
1970 vintage transformer-rectifier charger is not capable of such "magic". The 10A rating means "I can provide 10 A safely. I can do more but everything above 10 A is a fire hazzard. And you have been warned!"

Another confusion may come from "battery" design.
Old lead-acid batteries are nothing but negaive pin -[anode - electrolyte - cathode]-[anode - electrolyte - cathode]-positive pin. There is nothing to regulate the current except for internal resistance of the battery. The resistance is defined by the electrolysis happening on the electrodes surfaces and the electrolyte.
This design is very robust with four drawbacks: It is heavy, it has low energetic density (VAh/kg), it contain lead an it contains sulphuric acid.
Li-Ion and Li-Pol cells are Jack-in-the-box compared to lead-acid batteries. Incorrect voltage, incorrect charging or discharging current leads to the battery spectacular failure. That is why the battery unit is almost always packaged as a battery of cells with control circuit all assembled in one package with two and more terminals.
The negotiation of the control circuit and charger goes as follows:

Charger: Who are you?
Battery: I'm battery control unit. I can handle up to X volts and up to Y amperes.
Charger: Understood. Sending x<=X volts and setting limit to y<=Y amps.
or Charger: I don't understand. Sending safe default voltage x volts and setting current limit to y. (Hope x<X and y<Y, expect x<<X, y<<Y).


The other confusion - half the voltage, double the current miss one crucial part: For given, constant power output/throughput.
For transformers it means that if the primary is powered by 230 V and secondary provide 2.3 V then for every ampere "consumed" by the load on the secondary, the primary will "drain" 10 mA.
It also means that 1.1kW european kettle can use 5A rated circuitry (230 * 5=1150) while american kettle needs 10A rated circuit (110 * 10=1100). The heating element for europeant kettle should be 48ohm but american kettle needs 11ohm heting element. If you try european kettle in US it will behave as 250 W kettle and warm the water slowly, if you try american in Europe, it will try to be 4.8kW kettle and blow up. (expecting the kettle is just resistor, thermostat and switch)

In a modern USB-powered charger, the PWM is in a switching regulator to step the voltage up or down.  The current over the USB cable is close to constant, and so is the battery current (I'm pretty sure?) since they use capacitors to filter the output of the buck converter.  What matters for charging a battery is amp-hours of charge, not power / energy, so RMS isn't relevant. If you did use varying current, the plain average (integral of current over time) would be what mattered.

I'm quite sure you cannot step voltage up using PWM. I was using PWM to regulate power source for magnetron sputtering and PWM did not affect peak voltage at all. It affected the mean value and RMS. Amp-hours do matter but they translate to volt-amp-hours wich IS power. My point was new chargers and battery units can negotiate charging parameters, old chargers and batteries go all-in.

USB chargers (like a phone charging its internal battery) negotiate power delivery over the USB cable, which feeds a switching power supply (boost or buck) to get the right voltage for the actual battery.  A boost or buck converter can vary its duty cycle depending on load, but yeah I shouldn't have called that PWM.  Anyway, are you talking about the charger circuitry negotiating something with the actual cells, to control its output, rather than negotiating its power input over the USB cable?

I'm talking about charger negotiating its output with battery control unit what input it needs. The fate of the cells is completely in hands of the control unit.

Oh, so when you say "charger", you mean the AC adapter that supplies power to a USB cable?  Not the actual circuitry that puts current through electrochemical cells?  Yes, PWM could work for delivering some amount of power to the DC-DC converter that actually charges the cells.

Oh, you were talking about the actual chargers. I was talking about marketed chargers.

Yeah.  The OP was talking about a 1970's charger whose specs sound plausible for a car battery, which is just raw lead-acid cells.  Your comparison between that charger and USB power supplies (which you call chargers) seems highly likely to lead to confusion, especially without much text to clarify the difference.  (Also, is the current over the USB cable itself really PWMed?  I thought even with USB power delivery negotiation, it would be a somewhat regulated 5, 12, or 20 volts DC.)
